# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a search using [this](http://lugolabs.com/articles/20-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-ruby-on-rails) tutorial -

I followed all the instructions , but while initialising jQueryUI i' m getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` error in the following code.

```
_initAutocomplete: function() {
this._input
.autocomplete({
  source: '/search',
  appendTo: '#software-search-results',
  select: $.proxy(this._select, this)
}).autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = $.proxy(this._render, this);
}
```

browser says error is in the line `_initAutocomplete: function() {`

I checked the `source` url i have provided which is `/search` and it is returning `json` itself. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is somewhat misleading, because there's context missing to the snippet you posted. This is meant to be added to a configuration object and then passed to a method, e.g.

```
doSomething({_initAutocomplete: function() {...}})
```

Here's how the code is supposed to look like: https://github.com/lugolabs/tutorials/blob/5192a1f93c62a5140cdf253d8030d907086de3bc/amazing/app/assets/javascripts/books.js#L7

Comment: In your(OP) case I guess its `app.Books.prototype = {
  _initAutocomplete: function() {...}}`